# Detect offset of written data

Tags: c, file-io

I would like to create a file that indexes the offsets of the data chunks it contains. When appending these data chunks to the file, how can I detect the offset of the appended data chunk?

Also, if the indexing data is placed above the actual added data, how can one handle the crossing of indexing data and the initial start offset of the added data?

Answer (score 0):

If the stream is open in binary mode, then you can use `ftell()` to find the current file offset before you append data.